# GRMustache pass constant values in filter?

Tags: ios, mustache

I am trying to define an `isEquals` filter in GRMustache that would let me write a template like this:

```
{{# isEquals(item, "myConstant") }}
    Stuff here ...
{{/}}
```

I define `isEquals` in my objective-c code and it gets passed to the template.

The problem is that `isEquals` receives "item" fine, but receives null instead of "myConstant". I really want the constants defined in the templates (not in the code), since `isEquals` will be used differently in different templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRMustache author, here.

There is no support for string literals in the library.

You may consider those alternate solutions:

- naming your constants: `{{# isEqual(item, ThatValue) }}`
- declaring template-targeted properties: `{{# item.isThatValue }}`
- using a template engine which supports string literals, such as handlebars-objc.